# Group by date intervalsI

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have data in the format

```
+----------+-------------+
|Customerid|DateofJoining|
+----------+-------------+
|1         |aug 1        |
+----------+-------------+
|2         |aug 1        |
+----------+-------------+
|3         |aug 10       |
+----------+-------------+
|4         |aug 10       |
+----------+-------------+
|5         |aug 10       |
+----------+-------------+
|6         |sept 5       |
+----------+-------------+
```

So I want to show the result
Num of customers as progression of time

```
+--------------+------+
|TotalCustomers|Date  |
+--------------+------+
|2             |Aug 1 |
+--------------+------+
|5             |Aug 10|
+--------------+------+
|6             |Sept 5|
+--------------+------+
```

How do I do that.

With group by I can show total customers on any given date, but not the sum until then. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(numcustomersjoined), dateofjoining
FROM foo
GROUP BY dateofjoining
```

But that does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include version of sql-server. This will work for sqlserver-2012:

```
create table foo(Customerid int, DateofJoining date)
insert into foo values 
(1,'2014-08-01'),(2,'2014-08-01'),(3,'2014-08-10'),
(4,'2014-08-10'),(5,'2014-08-10'),(6,'2014-09-05')

SELECT
DateofJoining,
SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY dateofjoining) CumulativeTotal
FROM foo
GROUP BY DateofJoining
```

Result:

```
DateofJoining  CumulativeTotal
2014-08-01     2
2014-08-10     5
2014-09-05     6
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. I will edit my question. This is an awesome approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows that you want to get the highest `customerId` joined on particular date.

For that you can use `max` function.

```
select max(Customerid), dateofjoining from foo group by dateofjoining
```

Comment: This will work as long as there are no gabs in customerid and the date of joining follow the customerid and customerid starts at 1. As soon as there is a cleanup in the data, or a gap caused by rollback this will not give the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(Customerid), dateofjoining FROM foo GROUP BY dateofjoining;
```

Try this...

Comment: why do you post an identical answer that was given by someone else 8 minutes earlier ?

Comment: it was just some 30 secs, When i first seen the question and no one answered that time, i've worked this query and posted without refreshing the page.. it's my mistake, sorry. @t-clausen.dk

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a **[running total](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total)**. Let's supose [this scenario:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0879b/1)

```
create table t( Customerid int, DateofJoining date );
insert into t values 
(1 ,               '2014-08-01' ),
(12,               '2014-08-01' ),
(53,               '2014-08-10' ),
(14,               '2014-08-10' ),
(5 ,               '2014-08-10' ),
(96,               '2014-09-05' )
```

Then you can **running total** count with this non equijoin:

```
;with 
 slots as
(select
 distinct DateofJoining
 from t
)
select
 count(*) as n,
 slots.DateofJoining
from 
 t inner join slots
 on t.DateofJoining <= slots.DateofJoining  --non equijoin
group by
 slots.DateofJoining
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0879b/1/0)**:

```
| N | DATEOFJOINING |
|---|---------------|
| 2 |    2014-08-01 |
| 5 |    2014-08-10 |
| 6 |    2014-09-05 |
```